# How animate for delete action in dataTable?

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatable

I have a piece of code that delete a record and reload dataTable. I want to animate this action as such that on click the button the record of dataTable fade out and then delete from Data Base.
this is my code:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
        var _id = $(this).attr("id");
        data._id = $(this).attr("id");
        data.operation = "deleteorderdetail";
        // alert(data.operation);
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'delete.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data,
                success: function(data) {
                    $(this).parentsUntil("tr").hide(1000); -----> not work !                        
                    dataTable.ajax.reload();
                }
            });
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

Best regards....

Answer (score 0):

for **Datatable** try this may help you
try like this

```
   var row = $(this).closest('tr');
                        row.fadeOut(400, function () {
                            dataTable.row(row).remove().draw(false);
                        });
```

```js
 $(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
        var _id = $(this).attr("id");
        data._id = $(this).attr("id");
        data.operation = "deleteorderdetail";
        // alert(data.operation);
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'delete.php',
                method: 'POST',
                data,
                success: function(data) {
                  var row = $(this).closest('tr');
                    row.fadeOut(400, function () {
                        dataTable.row(row).remove().draw(false);
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: not work for me! I am using DATATABLE plugin....

Comment: check now it's may work!

Comment: I checked it again . The record removed but without any animate...

Comment: now, simply add animation I updated the code to check this may helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the following changes to your approach:

1. Capture the clicked item into its own variable:

```js
var clickedItem = $(this);
```

2. Use this clicked item when you select the row to be hidden.
3. Instead of using `parentsUntil`, use `closest`. Using `parentsUntil` will select every ancestor from your clicked object up to *but not including* the selected element (the `<tr>` in your case). I assume that what you want is to hide the entire row.

The reason for performing step 1: If you try to use `$(this).closest("tr").hide(1000);`, then `$(this)` will refer to the jQuery Ajax object in which `$(this)` is located.

The end result:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {
  var clickedItem = $(this); // capture clicked item
  var _id = $(this).attr("id");
  data._id = $(this).attr("id");
  data.operation = "deleteorderdetail";
  if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'delete.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data,
      success: function(data) {
        clickedItem.closest("tr").hide(1000); // use clicked item                 
        dataTable.ajax.reload();
      }
    });
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: It's not work. I did not see desired result. I think the reload() method prevents to see desired result

Comment: @mhm.map you tried ?  row.fadeOut(400, function () {
                        dataTable.row(row).remove().draw(false);
                    });

Comment: This approach works for me, so there may be some information missing from the question.